# Mount Ubuntu .disk file as Virtual Drive on Windows

Tags: windows, ubuntu, wubi, virtual-drive

I installed Ubuntu "on" Windows Vista using the Wubi installer.

The Ubuntu "disk" files are located in `C:\ubuntu\disks\`. (So, there's a large 30GB `.disk` file in that directory.)

How can I "mount" it so that I can easily access my Ubuntu files using Windows Explorer?

For example:

[image]

---

P.S. I haven't used any "partitions" or anything.

Comment: Windows can't read Linux filesystems without [installing a special driver](http://www.fs-driver.org/).  It will be far easier to mount the Windows drive from Ubuntu instead.

Comment: @Patches If I do that, will I be able to "see" Ubuntu from Windows, like in the image above? I tried fs-driver, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: No, you'll only be able to access it from Ubuntu.  The above driver actually doesn't appear to work with modern Linux filesystems.  [ext2read](http://ext2read.sf.net/) does supports both modern filesystems and reading wubi disk images.  Unfortunately, it provides only read only support and you must use a special program, not the standard Windows file access interfaces.

Comment: @Patches Will converting Ubuntu to some kind of partition do the trick? What if I used ISO?

Comment: It's possible the IFS driver will work when Ubuntu is installed as a partition, but I'm not sure.  Generally Linux users have one or more partitions assigned for Linux use that Windows never touches, a partition for Windows that Linux never touches, and then a third partition used specifically designed to be accessible from both systems and store files used by both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up moving Wubi to a new partition, and then installing [Ext2 driver](http://www.fs-driver.org/) for Windows and [Ext2FSD](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2fsd/), in that order. (Not sure which driver is the one that did it, but oh well.)

---

### Partitioning Wubi

1. Shrink the Windows [partition](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/partitioning) using Vista's [built-in tool](http://www.vistarewired.com/2007/02/16/how-to-resize-a-partition-in-windows-vista). (If you encounter problems, click [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/working-around-windows-vistas-shrink-volume-inadequacy-problems/).)
2. Create a bunch of partitions.

   - Vista's tool is inadequate if you want to create more than four partitions. (Or plan on doing so in the future.)
   - Reboot into Ubuntu, run GParted to create a new extended partition. Then put a bunch of logical partitions underneath that. **Do not** *move* the Windows partitions. (You may resize them, but *don't* move them.)
3. [Move Wubi](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1519354) to the new partition.

---

### Automatically Mount Partitions in Ubuntu

Why does the Windows volume need to be mounted every time you boot into Ubuntu? [Wanna fix it?](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticallyMountPartitions)

(If that doesn't work, try one of these: [LINK 1](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=820624), [LINK 2](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=432659).)

---

### Mount Linux Partitions in Windows

Use [Ext2 driver](http://www.fs-driver.org/) for Windows and/or [Ext2FSD](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2fsd/), as mentioned above. If they don't work for you, you're stuck with the alternatives on [this list](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/tools-to-access-linux-partitions-from-windows.html) or [this list](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-read-ext3ext4-linux-partition-from-windows-7.html).